# Images overflowing borders

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having an issue with images overflowing the set border for link type posts on my tumblr blog. I've tried re sizing width and height ratios and percentages for images, and yet I haven't been able to fix the issue. This also isn't an issue for images on of any other post types.

[image]

Here is the code that I'm *pretty sure* dictates the appearance of this.

```
    .post.link .postcontainer{
        padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding-bottom:5px;
    }

    .post.link .description{
        padding-left:20px;
        padding-right:60px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }


    .post.link a.postlink{
        font-family:"Helvetica Neue", helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
        font-size:12;
        color:#000;
        font-weight:bold;
        width:428px;
        padding-right:70px;
        display:block;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-decoration:none;

    }

    .post.link a.postlink span{
        background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/PHAkloide/icon-linkpost-arrow.png) no-repeat top left; 
        width:35px;
        height:36px;    
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        right:20px;
        top:50%;
        margin-top:-17px;
        opacity: .7;
        -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .post.link a.postlink:hover span{
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
    }

    .post.link .vialink{
        margin-left:20px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add some `html` example code that shows what's happening in the image?

Comment: can u post a fiddle sample or a working link to get a clear picture??

Comment: Um, here's a link to the permalink page: http://grumpyvich.tumblr.com/post/105855669032/matthew-gilberts-picks-for-tvs-best-shows-in

Comment: I'm not too sure how to add a fiddle example, sorry (first time using this site)

Answer (score 2):

For images, its ideally to add the following CSS rule:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue in your question @Alex, perhaps scope it a little more by adding e.g. `.postcontainer img { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Where should I insert this? I've tried a few places and they either don't do anything, or change the link so it no longer acts as a link, but rather as plain text.

Comment: Anywhere in your CSS, or the Custom CSS block.

Answer (score 0):

When you set width to 100% it takes the width of content box. It will be fine when you don't have any padding or border. But, when you add border, then the width of border will be added to the 100% and it will be more than 100% which causes the overflow. So to include the border within the 100% you should set `box-sizing` property in css of image.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```